# How do I find a good mutual fund to invest 5K in with a moderately high amount of risk?

Tags: mutual-funds

I have 5k to invest in stock market but do not want to select individual stocks. I would do it through mutual funds. I am willing to accept a moderately high amount of risk.  How can I find a good mutual fund that meets these criteria?

Comment: Harry, where are you located?  U.S.A., or elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Just find a low cost S&P 500 index fund, and spend your time reading [The Great Mutual Fund Trap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0767910729) instead of wasting your time and money picking actively managed funds.

Comment: 38 or so shares of SPY (about $5k) can be bought (and later sold) for under $10 per transaction at several brokerages. Low cost, liquid, easy.

Comment: Vanguard's VOO isn't quiiiite as liquid but it's pretty close and if you have a Vanguard brokerage account, you can trade it for ***$0 per trade***. That's right, free. Also, its expense ratio is .06% to SPY's .09%. Not that both aren't dirt cheap.

Answer (score 2):

The "Money 70" is a fine list:
http://money.cnn.com/magazines/moneymag/bestfunds/index.html

Money magazine is usually more reasonable than the other ones (SmartMoney, Kiplinger's, etc. are in my opinion sillier).

If you want a lot of depth, the Morningstar Analyst Picks are useful but you have to pay for a membership which is probably not worth it for now:
http://www.morningstar.com/Cover/Funds.aspx
(side note: Morningstar star ratings are not useful, I'd ignore those. analyst picks are pretty useful.)

Vanguard is a can't-go-too-wrong suggestion. They don't have any house funds that are "bad," while for example Fidelity has some good ones mixed with a bunch that aren't so much. Of course, some funds at Vanguard may be inappropriate for your situation. (Vanguard also sells third-party funds, I'm talking about their own branded funds.)

If getting started with 5K I think you'd want to go with an all-in-one fund like a target date retirement fund or a balanced fund. Such a fund also handles rebalancing for you. There's a Vanguard target date fund and balanced fund (Wellington) in the Money 70 list.

fwiw, I think it's more important to ask how much risk you need to take, rather than how much you are willing to take. I wrote this down at more length here:
http://blog.ometer.com/2010/11/10/take-risks-in-life-for-savings-choose-a-balanced-fund/

First pick your desired asset allocation, then pick your fund after that to match.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Vanguard has a lot of mutual fund offerings.  (I have an account there.)  Within the members' section they give indications of the level of risk/reward for each fund.

Comment: Here's the page you're looking for. It's not a members-only section. https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/vanguard/core  -- sounds like the poster might appreciate the Wellington fund, VWELX?